# Как задать ссылку на файл для чтения в Linux, если директории с файлом на ПК, где ведется разработка и на сервере разные?

Tags: java, linux, spring-mvc, tomcat, java-8

Пишу Java-Spring приложение на локальном ПК (Windows). В данном приложении, при нажатии на кнопку идет считывание данных из файла Excel, путь к которому прописан в строковой переменной ("E:..."). Я это приложение размещаю на удаленном сервере (Linux). Это делаю закидывая war-архив в Tomcat и авто деплоя. Путь к файлу, из которого следует считывать данные, на сервере уже соответственно другой (/opt/tomcat/webapps/.../).

Как задать ссылку на файл для чтения, если директории с файлом на ПК, где ведется разработка и на сервере разные?

Попробовал 3-и способа задать с помощью относительной ссылки относительно директории приложения:
1)

```
    @Autowired
ServletContext servletContext;

String wayPath=servletContext.getContextPath();// "/fast"
```

Он вернул "/fast", которая находится в "/opt/tomcat/webapps/". Если я туда кидаю свой файл, то после запуска приложения он просто удаляется. Поэтому на мой относительный путь "Hydrometcentre.xls" вылетает исключение - Файл не найден.

2)

```
import java.io.File;

String wayPath2=new File(".").getAbsolutePath();// "E:\Fast_w\apache-tomcat-9.0.19\bin\."
```

Он возвращает - "E:\Fast_w\apache-tomcat-9.0.19\bin.".Это директория самого Tomcat.
У себя на ПК у меня не возникает проблем закинуть туда файл и прочитать его по относительному пути в приложении, а вот на сервере с этим проблема:

> > Root Cause java.lang.NullPointerException org.apache.poi.poifs.filesyste m.POIFSFileSystem.closeInputSt
> >     ream(POIFSFileSystem.java:333) org.apache.poi.poifs.filesyste
> >     m.POIFSFileSystem.(POIFS FileSystem.java:321)
> >     org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel. HSSFWorkbook.(HSSFWorkbo
> >     ok.java:401) org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.
> >     HSSFWorkbook.(HSSFWorkbo ok.java:382)
> >     **service.ReadExcel.readExcelAll (ReadExcel.java:139)** controller.UserController.admi nistration(UserController.java :134)
> >     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccess orImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> >     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccess orImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAcce
> >     ssorImpl.java:62) sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAc
> >     cessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMe thodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >     java.lang.reflect.Method.invok e(Method.java:498)
> >     org.springframework.web.method .support.InvocableHandlerMetho
> >     d.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMet hod.java:189)
> >     org.springframework.web.method .support.InvocableHandlerMetho
> >     d.invokeForRequest(InvocableHa ndlerMethod.java:138)
> >     org.springframework.web.servle t.mvc.method.annotation.Servle
> >     tInvocableHandlerMethod.invoke AndHandle(ServletInvocableHand
> >     lerMethod.java:102) org.springframework.web.servle
> >     t.mvc.method.annotation.Reques tMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeH
> >     andlerMethod(RequestMappingHan dlerAdapter.java:895)
> >     org.springframework.web.servle t.mvc.method.annotation.Reques
> >     tMappingHandlerAdapter.handleI nternal(RequestMappingHandlerA
> >     dapter.java:800) org.springframework.web.servle
> >     t.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMe thodAdapter.handle(AbstractHan
> >     dlerMethodAdapter.java:87) org.springframework.web.servle
> >     t.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch (DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
> >     org.springframework.web.servle t.DispatcherServlet.doService(
> >     DispatcherServlet.java:942) org.springframework.web.servle
> >     t.FrameworkServlet.processRequ est(FrameworkServlet.java:1005 )
> >     org.springframework.web.servle t.FrameworkServlet.doGet(Frame
> >     workServlet.java:897) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
> >     .service(HttpServlet.java:634) org.springframework.web.servle
> >     t.FrameworkServlet.service(Fra meworkServlet.java:882)
> >     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet .service(HttpServlet.java:741)
> >     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.se rver.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilte
> >     r.java:53)

139 строка, это где создается объект книги Excel:

```
FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(relationWay));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Get the workbook instance for XLS file
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
    try {
        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream); // 139 строка
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Может быть это из-за того, что владельцем директории куда я кидаю файл (/opt/tomcat/bin/) является root и пишется файл в данную директорию только под root?

3) попробовал прописать абсолютный путь на сервере, но выдаёт тоже самое исключение в 139 строке:

```
String relationWay="/opt/tomcat/webapps/water_war/Hydrometcentre.xls";//way
    // Read XSL file
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(relationWay));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Get the workbook instance for XLS file
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
    try {
        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Как можно задать этот путь? Может есть какой-нибудь костыль?
У меня всего 1-н такой файл.

Comment: проголосовал за закрытие предыдущего вашего идентичного вопроса как [дубликата](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1117304/178576) этого вопроса (здесь более развёрнута формулировка).

Comment: p.s. по теме вопроса. наверно, надо использовать разные конфигурации. что-нибудь типа такого: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1719857/4827341

Comment: Получилось найти решение проблемы самому

Answer (score 1):

Решение таково: в веб-проектах создаваемых в IDEA есть папка "resources", если её нет, то её можно добавить присвоив ей тип "Resources ...", далее в эту папку можно загружать нужные нам файлы, а в любой части проекта можно обращаться к ним следующим образом:

```
wayFile =new ClassPathResource(nameFile).getFile().getPath();
```

и использовать данный путь:

```
FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(wayFile));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

При сборке проекта данные файлы собираются в war-архив, а при деплое на сервере размещаются по пути webapps/nameProject/WEB-INF/classes, поэтому обновить их при необходимости не составит труда.